# Fractional differintegral for the reconstruction of time series

Tags: economics, time-series, fractional-calculus

How do economists and climatologists reconstruct their time series from the available data? I know in particular that economists have built models to extimate the GDP per capita between the year 0 and today from the last 100 years data.

Also, given that differintegral (as defined in fractional calulus) has a memory effect, can we use it for the reconstruction of time series? I know there are models such as fractional autoregressive integrated moving average that accounts for long memory effects, is it possible to define something like FARIMA models that reconstruct the past?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.